SSRS Email Subscription with File Iteration
I have a report that's output is too large to send in one email. Is it possible to set up a subscription that will send multiple emails splitting up by file iterations?

You could use a data-driven subscription to send a series of emails. Each one could have a page of data attached. Here's how you can go about adding this feature:

Add a page parameter to the report.
Add a filter to show the correct rows for the selected page. This filter could be in the SQL or in the dataset properties.
Create a data-driven subscription with a query that returns one row per page. You can use this page field from this dataset as the parameter for the report. This will cause the subscription to send out one email per page.

However, a better solution would be to have the subscription place the entire file into a shared folder and have a link to that folder in the body of the email.
